# Testing async http service - scope of error

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a http async service.

My Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/menu';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  async getMenus() {
    return this.httpClient.get<MenuData[]>(this.url).toPromise();
  }
}
```

My test

```
describe('MenuService', () => {
  let service: MenuService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [MenuService],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(MenuService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should get all menus', async () => {

    const menus = service.getMenus().then((data: MenuData[]) => {
      expect(data.length).toBe(2);
    });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:8080/rest/menu', 'call to api');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    req.flush([<MenuData>{id: 1, name: 'Test', discreteSubMenus: false, subMenus: false}]);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```

Test results look the following

[image]

This is the test result if i change the `async getMenus()` to

```
 getMenus(): Observable<MenuData[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<MenuData[]>(this.url);
  }
```

[image]

Which looks more correct. Because the MenuService Test failed and not the whole test. How can I change my test code to correctly test the async method?

Answer (score 0):

For writing services to backend I would always go with `Observables` if I have a choice.

You can change your `Service` method to

```
getMenus(): Observable<MenuData[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<MenuData[]>(this.url);
  }
```

And your test method changes to

```
      it('should get all menus', async () => {

       //Prepare Mock Menu Data
       let mockMenu = [<MenuData>{id: 1, name: 'Test', discreteSubMenus: false, subMenus: false}];

        const menus = service.getMenus().subscribe((data: MenuData[]) => {
          expect(data.length).toBe(2);
          // Other asserts about the received response here
        });  

        // Asserts of the api call here    
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:8080/rest/menu', 'call to api');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');    
        req.flush(mockMenu);
      });
```

Comment: Is it correct to declare the function `async` when it is not returning a promise or using any `await` keywords?

Comment: if you are  using `Observables` no need for async. Also if there are no `promise`s you are `await`ing inside a method, `async` will have no impact. With angular , unless forced, try to use `Observables` :)
If the solution helped, please accept, this will help others to find the answers in case of similar situations

Comment: Yes Observable would solve the problem, but a solution would still be nice for async/promise

Comment: Can you setup a quick stackblitz link, I'll try tosee why promise is failing ?